# How long the pregnancy to produce a "Curious" badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I just got the following achievement:

> You've earned the "Curious" badge (Asked a good question on 5 separate days, and maintains a positive question record.).

It is indeed curious, and I am curious too. I am wondering why I received it a bit more than 9 months after my last question.

Of course, that duration rings a bell, but I somehow doubt it is the real reason.
Anyone knows more ?

Comment: The badge was just created last night or so. See the Meta post about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges

Comment: Thanks **:)))**

Comment: That's why I woke up to 4 new badges! Ironically on some sites I'm no longer very curious about...

Comment: That would be ''incubation period'' (in the title) :)

Comment: @New_new_newbie Thanks ... but *incubation* connotes a disease, not the gestation of a positive event. Though I must confess that my title was in jest, suggesting of course to make the jestation shorter.

Comment: Haha. But why only a disease? Hatching eggs is also called incubation. [See here for example](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incubation?q=incubation). I meant in this sense.     Cheers anyways :)

Comment: You are right. But, it is somewhat a misnomer in the case of eggs. Have you
ever seen a cubic egg? Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you got the badge retroactively today because we just implemented it today.  See: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) for more details.

In the future, the badges will be awarded shortly after the criteria is met. Since the criteria involves votes and closed question and such, it might still be a while after asking your last question, however. Suppose you had 4 days of asking well-received questions and one day asking a question with no votes. If I come along 9 months later and upvote that question, the criteria will be met and the badge awarded.

Comment: I assumed that a delay was necessary before awarding such a badge, but
9 months seemed a long time. That said, a question could be downvoted
a long time after it was asked and upvoted. For example, there is one
old accepted answer that I believe to be nonsense, and I hope will be
removed.